# Attempted import error in react app but the path and everything is correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, export

I am receiving the following error : `Attempted import error: 'MyPropertiesForm' is not exported from '../../forms'.` and I cannot figure out why because everything is correct.

Here is how I import `import { MyPropertiesForm } from '../../forms';`

> // this file is in
> E:\falala\src\containers\MyPropertiesPage\MyPropertiesPage.js

And here is how I export

```
const MyPropertiesForm = compose(injectIntl)(MyPropertiesFormComponent);
MyPropertiesForm.displayName = 'ContactDetailsForm';
export default MyPropertiesForm;
```

> //this file is in
> E:\falala\src\forms\MyPropertiesForm\MyPropertiesForm.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import  MyPropertiesForm  from '../../forms/MyPropertiesForm/MyPropertiesForm';
```

Pay attention that the path you gave was only to the "form" folder but the export was actually in a file deep inside that folder.

And also pay attention that when you import a default exported module so you don't write it inside {} but write it as is named.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked !!! But I still don't quite undestand why. I know if it's a default export it shouldn't be imported with curly braces, but why is " import  MyPropertiesForm  from './../../forms/MyPropertiesForm/MyPropertiesForm'; " and not " import  MyPropertiesForm  from './../../forms/MyPropertiesForm/MyPropertiesForm.js'; "  How does the import knows which MyPropertiesForm I want to import from, the is a css with the same name in there too.

Comment: the `.js` is not needed because there is a "[JS Bundler](https://medium.com/@gimenete/how-javascript-bundlers-work-1fc0d0caf2da)" (such as Webpack) which tells the compiler to refer to it exactly as a .js file. So actually it is adjusted to act like this from the beginning...